# Why does my heap not fill its pages completely while an identical clustered index can fill to m_freeCnt = 0?

Tags: sql-server-2008, storage-engine

-- Example 1: With Clustered Index

```
CREATE TABLE tbl5 
(
    i VARCHAR(900) NOT NULL 
) ;
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_tbl5
    ON tbl5 (i ASC) ;
GO

INSERT      INTO tbl5
            ( i )
VALUES
            ( REPLICATE('a' , 900) )
    ,       ( REPLICATE('b' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('c' , 900) )
    ,       ( REPLICATE('d' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('e' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('f' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('g' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('h' , 900) )  -- 900 x 8  + (13 x 8) = 7200 + 104 = 7304
    ,       ( REPLICATE('i' , 761) ) ;-- 7304 + 761 + 13  
GO                                    -- = 8078 + 96(Page Header) + 18 (Slot)
                                      -- = 8192
                                      -- m_freeCnt = 0

DBCC IND(tempdb,tbl5,-1) ; -- everything is IN_ROW_DATA
GO
DBCC TRACEON(3604) ;
GO
DBCC PAGE(tempdb,1,177,3) ;
GO
```

-- Example 2: With heap. When column 'i' is 392 m_freeCnt = 387. When 'i' = 393, I get a new page. Why can I not add more bytes to 'i'?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl6
(
    i VARCHAR(900) NOT NULL 
) ;
GO
INSERT      INTO tbl6
            ( i )
VALUES
            ( REPLICATE('a' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('b' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('c' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('d' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('e' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('f' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('g' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('h' , 900) ) 
    ,       ( REPLICATE('i' , 393) ) ;
GO

DBCC IND(tempdb,tbl6,-1); 
GO
DBCC TRACEON(3604);
GO
DBCC PAGE(tempdb,1,181,3);
GO
```

Comment: When the final row is of length `392` you can see loads of free space on the page in SQL Internals Viewer [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZtT8.png). Maybe something to do with PFS units?

Comment: @Martin if only I could get SSQL Internals Viewer to work on my 08R2 system! =-) I'll dig in further.

Comment: Do you mind updating your scripts to use [row constructors](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2007/12/05/2008-initializing-table-data-with-row-constructors.aspx)? It would make them much, much, shorter and easier to read.

Comment: @nick Done, sorry about the slop

Comment: @ooutwire - Sweet!  The post looks much better now. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'page split' and 'heap' should not be used in the same sentence. Do you mean why wasn't the row of size 393+change fit in the free space of the first page of the heap? That is because the PFS free space info has not high enough resolution, see [Managing Extent Allocations and Free Space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175195.aspx):

> The PFS has one byte for each page, recording whether the page is
>   allocated, and if so, whether it is empty, 1 to 50 percent full, 51 to
>   80 percent full, 81 to 95 percent full, or 96 to 100 percent full.

Would fit in page, indeed, but the PFS only says that the page is '95_PCT_FULL' and the record inserted is fairly big and close to the free space as-per-PFS (95% of 8060 is 403), so the INSERT chooses to allocate a new page.

With a B-Tree the record position is deterministic due to key order, so the engine **must** load the page and check the free space, and the record will fit.

Comment: Thank you. I did not intend to write "page split"; I was asking, as you correctly deduced, why won't the row fit onto the first page.

Comment: Note how if you reduce the size to 392 chars the resulted record (which fits and does not cause 'split') has *exactly* 403 bytes length, ie. the 95% mark. 393 crosses the threshold.

Comment: It is odd though that I cannot always repeat my results. Sometimes I can actually get the page full. I'll continue to experiment.